# Change the Style of an XtraReport an an ASPX Page for Printing

Tags: c#, asp.net, colors, devexpress, xtrareport

To get an XtraReport to match my web site, I have had to set the background color to something other than white. But when the user Prints the report, I would like the background to default back to white.

I can't see how I could use an @media tag in the style sheet for this, and I have tried capturing the BeforePrint event and setting it there. Nothing seems to be working. I just want the background color set back to white before printing. No reason to waste a lot of ink.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review the http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q343628 discussion in the DevExpress support center. Hope this helps.